# How to merge duplicate Firestore documents?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a function that loops through an array and creates a new document in the Firestore database with an `id` and `quantity` fields for each element in the array but I want the function to merge the documents if the another document with the same id already exists
I tried the following code:

```
 useEffect(() => {

 !Locked && User && Uid && items &&
 items.forEach(item=>
  
      User && db.collection("users").doc(Uid).collection("basket").add({
        id : item.id,
        quantity : item.quantity
    }, {merge: true})
    .then(setLocked(true))
    )

  }, [items, User,Locked,Uid])
```

but it did not work then I tried to change the `.add` to `.set` but it shows the following error:

```
TypeError: _backend_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__.db.collection(...).doc(...).collection(...).set is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `set` on a collection. You can only write to a document within that collection.

You will to first need to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) to find the duplicate document, and *then* update that document.

---

If each `item.id` has to be unique within a user's `basket`, consider using the item Id as the document ID, instead of calling `add`:

```
User && db.collection("users").doc(Uid).collection("basket").doc(item.id).set({
    id : item.id,
    quantity : item.quantity
}, {merge: true})
```

This makes it much easier to update the document later, as you can write to the document based on its document/item id again, rather than needing a query.